# Handler for group in Aiogram

Tags: aiogram

I was preparing a bot for groups using the aiogram module @ dp.message_handler only receives chat messages I needed information on all group activities Is there such a handler?

Answer (score 2):

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    print(message)

print out:

{"message_id": 8395, "from": {"id": 701286603, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Игорь", "last_name": "Grach", "username": "toynbee", "language_code": "ru"}, "chat": {"id": 701286603, "first_name": "Игорь", "last_name": "Grach", "username": "toynbee", "type": "private"}, "date": 1645073825, "text": "test"}
{"message_id": 8396, "from": {"id": 701286603, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Игорь", "last_name": "Grach", "username": "toynbee", "language_code": "ru"}, "chat": {"id": 701286603, "first_name": "Игорь", "last_name": "Grach", "username": "toynbee", "type": "private"}, "date": 1645073830, "reply_to_message": {"message_id": 8395, "from": {"id": 701286603, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Игорь", "last_name": "Grach", "username": "toynbee", "language_code": "ru"}, "chat": {"id": 701286603, "first_name": "Игорь", "last_name": "Grach", "username": "toynbee", "type": "private"}, "date": 1645073825, "text": "test"}, "text": "test_reply"}
```

[image]

There were two tests.
Reaction to a simple message.
Reaction to reply

If you need a response to photos, videos, documents - you can add `content_types = ['photo', 'video','document']`

Comment: Unable to get group internal information

Comment: Changed the answer, but most likely I misunderstood you

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle only groups - try  adding `chat_type=` to handler args:

```
@dp.message_handler(chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def group_handler(message: Message):
    print(message.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP], chat_id=123321)
async def group_handler(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(message.text)
```

it'll work